Rust lifetimes in structs
Why is it not working?
struct Test<'s>(&'s mut i32);

impl<'n, 's: 'n> Test<'s> {
    fn new(i: &'s mut i32) -> Self {
        Self(i)
    }

    fn cast(&'s mut self) -> Test<'n> {
        Test(self.0)
    }

    fn mutate(&mut self) {
        self.0.add_assign(10);
        println!("Mutate: {}", self.0);
    }
}

fn test() {
    let mut i = 5;
    let mut a = Test::new(&mut i);
    {
        a.cast().mutate(); // first borrowing 
    }
    a.mutate(); // second borrowing
}


Rust said, that i cannot borrow a as mutable more than once at time.
But am i not drop borrowing with braces?
How it is work and what i need to do to make it work

Because &'a mut T<'a> (&'s mut self in your example) is always wrong.

Can you will explain why? In my mind i say rust that self lifetime('s) less than 'n. It is illegal?

First, 's: 'n means 's outlives 'n, i.e. bigger. But everything is explained in the duplicate.
